# import cv2 ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes

Tags: python

I use jupyter vscode on my Windows OS. When I import cv2, it is always reports that ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes.

```
      1 import os
----> 2 import cv2
      3 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
```

When I try to reinstall opencv, it fails and still seems to reports this error.

````
```ERROR: Exception:
Installing collected packages: opencv-python
  Attempting uninstall: opencv-python
    Found existing installation: opencv-python 4.6.0.66
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 160, in exc_logging_wrapper
    status = run_func(*args)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 247, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 494, in run
    installed = install_given_reqs(
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\__init__.py", line 68, in install_given_reqs
    uninstalled_pathset = requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\req_install.py", line 659, in uninstall
    uninstalled_pathset = UninstallPathSet.from_dist(dist)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\req_uninstall.py", line 526, in from_dist
    for path in uninstallation_paths(dist):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\req_uninstall.py", line 45, in unique
    for item in fn(*args, **kw):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\req_uninstall.py", line 85, in uninstallation_paths
    for entry in entries:
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\metadata\base.py", line 472, in <genexpr>
    return (str(pathlib.Path(row[0])) for row in csv.reader(text.splitlines()))
_csv.Error: line contains NUL
````

Comment: You should try re-installing OpenCV

Comment: Another possibility is that you created another file `cv2.py`, if so, rename that.

Comment: I try to re-install OpenCV, but it still reports this error.